# Sliding time window with python deque

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, deque

I have deque. Each element of the deque consists of **time** and **event** field. So, this is similar to list of dicts. Data is always sorted by time from oldest to newest. First element of the deque is the oldest.

Please, note that **deque is infinite** and every time new element(s) are added with unknown time. This means that new element can be added after 1 minute or after 1 hour. Who knows...

```
data = [
        {
            "time": "07:14:40",
            "event": 24
        },
        {
            "time": "07:15:40",
            "event": 394
        },
        {
            "time": "07:16:40",
            "event": 384
        },
        {
            "time": "07:17:40",
            "event": 394
        },
        {
            "time": "07:18:40",
            "event": 384
        },
        {
            "time": "07:19:40",
            "event": 2
        },
        {
            "time": "07:20:40",
            "event": 24
        },
        {
            "time": "07:21:40",
            "event": 72
        },
        {
            "time": "07:22:40",
            "event": 24
        },
        {
            "time": "07:23:40",
            "event": 72
        },
        {
            "time": "07:24:40",
            "event": 99
        }
    ]
```

I'm also given window size. Let it be 5 minutes.

I want to iterate over this deque with the given window size and calculate **expanding moving sum**. Let me elaborate what does this mean.

During iteration over this deque, during every iteration, I have to check the current AND older elements if they are inside 5 minute window and sum them up. If older element(s) are outside of 5 minute window then pop them from deque.

In other words, during first iteration start date will be

```
07:09:40 - (going 5 minute back)
```

and end date will be

```
07:14:40
```

and sum will be 24.  During second iteration, as this element is not inside the date range then I have to redefine my date range in the following way:

start date will be

```
07:10:40
```

and end date will be

```
07:15:40
```

Now, I have to look back and check all previous elements. The date of the first element is

```
07:14:40
```

which is inside my new date range and I will do new summation (24 + 394)

During third iteration, the time field is outside my previous date range and then I have to redefine my date range in the same manner as I did during previous iteration and do all the summation similarly.

When I reach the following element (7th iteration)

```
"time": "07:20:40",
"event": 24
```

My date range will be:

start date:

```
07:15:40
```

end date:

```
07:20:40
```

**Then I have to look back and grab all the elements which time field is inside this date range.
Note that the first element is outside the date range and I have to pop out this first element from the deque.** - This is my question. How can I do this?

This is the code fragment I did but it does not work.

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict
```

```
window_size = 300

test = deque(sort_data(list(read_json("final_real_test.json").values())[0]))


result = defaultdict(list)
final_input = deque()

end_date = test[0]["time"]
start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(seconds=window_size)


while test:
    record = test.popleft()

    if start_date <= record["time"] <= end_date:
        # Calculate the sum
        final_input.append(record)
    else:
        end_date = record["time"]
        start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(seconds=window_size)

        print("Returning back to the queue...")
        test.appendleft(record)
        print("Done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not explain how your `deque` was updated, and how it should affect the window processing.

But here is a proof-of-concept of the algorithm :

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Generator, List, Dict, Union

Element = Dict[str, Union[str, int]]
Series = List[Element]

def sliding_window(series: Series, window_duration: int) -> Generator[Series, None, None]:
    time_format = "%H:%M:%S"
    if len(series) > 0:
        for i_ending_item, ending_item in enumerate(series):
            end_window_time = datetime.strptime(ending_item["time"], time_format)
            print(f"window ends at item n°{i_ending_item} ({end_window_time!r})")
            window = [ending_item]
            for window_candidate_item in reversed(series[0:max(i_ending_item, 0)]):
                candidate_time = datetime.strptime(window_candidate_item["time"], time_format)
                assert end_window_time > candidate_time
                candidate_delta = end_window_time - candidate_time
                print(f"  {candidate_time=!r} {candidate_delta=!r} {candidate_delta.seconds=!r}")
                if candidate_delta.seconds < window_duration:  # non inclusive
                    print("    added to the window")
                    window.insert(0, window_candidate_item)
                else:
                    print("  stop there")
                    break
            else:
                print("  reached the beginning of the series")
            yield window

DATA: Series = [
    {"time": "07:14:40", "event": 24},
    {"time": "07:15:40", "event": 394},
    {"time": "07:16:40", "event": 384},
    {"time": "07:17:40", "event": 394},
    {"time": "07:18:40", "event": 384},
    {"time": "07:19:40", "event": 2},
    {"time": "07:20:40", "event": 24},
    {"time": "07:21:40", "event": 72},
    {"time": "07:22:40", "event": 24},
    {"time": "07:23:40", "event": 72},
    {"time": "07:24:40", "event": 99}
]
WINDOW_SIZE = 5*60

for window in sliding_window(DATA, WINDOW_SIZE):
    print(window, "sum=", sum(item["event"] for item in window))
```

which produces

```py
window ends at item n°0 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 14, 40))
  reached the beginning of the series
[{'time': '07:14:40', 'event': 24}] sum= 24
window ends at item n°1 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 15, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 14, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  reached the beginning of the series
[{'time': '07:14:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:15:40', 'event': 394}] sum= 418
window ends at item n°2 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 16, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 15, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 14, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) candidate_delta.seconds=120
    added to the window
  reached the beginning of the series
[{'time': '07:14:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:15:40', 'event': 394}, {'time': '07:16:40', 'event': 384}] sum= 802
window ends at item n°3 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 17, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 16, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 15, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) candidate_delta.seconds=120
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 14, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=180) candidate_delta.seconds=180
    added to the window
  reached the beginning of the series
[{'time': '07:14:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:15:40', 'event': 394}, {'time': '07:16:40', 'event': 384}, {'time': '07:17:40', 'event': 394}] sum= 1196
window ends at item n°4 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 18, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 17, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 16, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) candidate_delta.seconds=120
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 15, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=180) candidate_delta.seconds=180
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 14, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=240) candidate_delta.seconds=240
    added to the window
  reached the beginning of the series
[{'time': '07:14:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:15:40', 'event': 394}, {'time': '07:16:40', 'event': 384}, {'time': '07:17:40', 'event': 394}, {'time': '07:18:40', 'event': 384}] sum= 1580
window ends at item n°5 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 19, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 18, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 17, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) candidate_delta.seconds=120
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 16, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=180) candidate_delta.seconds=180
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 15, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=240) candidate_delta.seconds=240
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 14, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=300) candidate_delta.seconds=300
  stop there
[{'time': '07:15:40', 'event': 394}, {'time': '07:16:40', 'event': 384}, {'time': '07:17:40', 'event': 394}, {'time': '07:18:40', 'event': 384}, {'time': '07:19:40', 'event': 2}] sum= 1558
window ends at item n°6 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 20, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 19, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 18, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) candidate_delta.seconds=120
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 17, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=180) candidate_delta.seconds=180
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 16, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=240) candidate_delta.seconds=240
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 15, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=300) candidate_delta.seconds=300
  stop there
[{'time': '07:16:40', 'event': 384}, {'time': '07:17:40', 'event': 394}, {'time': '07:18:40', 'event': 384}, {'time': '07:19:40', 'event': 2}, {'time': '07:20:40', 'event': 24}] sum= 1188
window ends at item n°7 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 21, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 20, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 19, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) candidate_delta.seconds=120
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 18, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=180) candidate_delta.seconds=180
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 17, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=240) candidate_delta.seconds=240
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 16, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=300) candidate_delta.seconds=300
  stop there
[{'time': '07:17:40', 'event': 394}, {'time': '07:18:40', 'event': 384}, {'time': '07:19:40', 'event': 2}, {'time': '07:20:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:21:40', 'event': 72}] sum= 876
window ends at item n°8 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 22, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 21, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 20, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) candidate_delta.seconds=120
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 19, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=180) candidate_delta.seconds=180
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 18, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=240) candidate_delta.seconds=240
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 17, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=300) candidate_delta.seconds=300
  stop there
[{'time': '07:18:40', 'event': 384}, {'time': '07:19:40', 'event': 2}, {'time': '07:20:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:21:40', 'event': 72}, {'time': '07:22:40', 'event': 24}] sum= 506
window ends at item n°9 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 23, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 22, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 21, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) candidate_delta.seconds=120
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 20, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=180) candidate_delta.seconds=180
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 19, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=240) candidate_delta.seconds=240
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 18, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=300) candidate_delta.seconds=300
  stop there
[{'time': '07:19:40', 'event': 2}, {'time': '07:20:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:21:40', 'event': 72}, {'time': '07:22:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:23:40', 'event': 72}] sum= 194
window ends at item n°10 (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 24, 40))
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 23, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) candidate_delta.seconds=60
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 22, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) candidate_delta.seconds=120
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 21, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=180) candidate_delta.seconds=180
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 20, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=240) candidate_delta.seconds=240
    added to the window
  candidate_time=datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 19, 40) candidate_delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=300) candidate_delta.seconds=300
  stop there
[{'time': '07:20:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:21:40', 'event': 72}, {'time': '07:22:40', 'event': 24}, {'time': '07:23:40', 'event': 72}, {'time': '07:24:40', 'event': 99}] sum= 291
```

To me it seems to answer your question : how to have a sliding window based on the time of the events.

I used a `list` for the data by simplicity. If you want to share a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be simpler to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @Lenormju. With the few modifications this is exactly what I needed to have